# When/how does the Audience Manager node appear in a Publication?

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1, audience-manager

In one of our Publications suddenly the Audience Manager node is visible in Content Manager Explorer. When/how does this node appear (Tridion 2013 SP1)? And how do you ensure this node is not visible in a Publication?

[image: Audience Manager node visible in Publicatoion]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It occurs when someone changes anything on the Audience Manager tab on the Publication and presses Save -- such as selecting a Synchronization Target, filling in a URL, choosing Address Books, etc.

Once a Publication has been marked as using Audience Manager, there isn't an easy way to un-mark it as such *in the UI*. But assuming it is indeed a mistake you can fix it by using the Audience Manager API -- by calling the Delete method on the [AM] Publication object.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this, without making changes on the Audience Manager tab in the Publication.  

In the Security tab, I added a new group and enabled the following rights:  
  
- Folder Management  
- Component Management  
- Publish to Content Distributor  
  
After hitting Save and Close, the Audience Manager node appeared in the Publication...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't pick an AM/OE related right too? Perhaps Outbound E-mail Folder Management? If not, please report it as a defect as it obviously should only make it an AM Publication if you use anything related to AM in it.